# In mplab xc8 IDE Is it safe use ei() the same way as the AVR Assembler sei()?

Tags: avr, pic, avr-gcc, microchip, xc8

GIVEN:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB_XC8_C_Compiler_User_Guide.pdf
XC8's ei(); // Enable Global interrupts

XC8's di(); // Disable Global interrupts

and

AVR's sei() http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_SEI.html

AVR's cli() http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_CLI.html

Then its safe to say ei() == sei() && di() == cli() and can be used interchangeably when switching platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very general statement about the interrupt systems on the two chips. They are very different in many ways.

That said, yes, the macros set and clear a single bit in a status register, so the macros operate the same way.

Answer (score 0):

How to set interrupt via XC8 for Atmega? I read
[MPLAB_XC8_C_Compiler_User_Guide_for_AVR](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB_XC8_C_Compiler_User_Guide_for_AVR.pdf).

An example of an interrupt function is shown below.

```
void __interrupt(SPI_STC_vect_num) spi_Isr(void) {    
//I coment this: process(SPI_SlaveReceive());  
return;
}
```

Error

```
../main.c:10:18: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
                 from ../main.h:3,
 void __interrupt(SPI_STC_vect_num) spi_Isr(void) {
```